# Reading .txt file saved in memory

Tags: c++, memory

I have a .txt file saved in memory ( void *Buffer; UINT itsLen ). Is there any easy way to read this text file like std::wifstream read txt from a disk?

Comment: Is `itsLen` the size of the buffer in bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; use a *string stream*.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

...

```
wchar_t* p = static_cast<wchar_t*>(Buffer);
std::wistringstream s(std::wstring(p, p + itsLen/sizeof(wchar_t)));
```

The string stream `s` can be used similarly to a `std::wifstream` object.